# Missing ";" before "type" with pointers in C

Tags: c

I am a total novice in C.  I am taking this class online and it is very difficult to get help.
I know this question has been asked and answered ad nauseam, but I can't seem to figure out what needs to be declared in the function.

Edit: I am using Visual Studio 2008.

The functions here are designed to make an entire string lower case and count the words in said string

The errors occur at the function call in main but I believe the real problem is in the functions themselves.
Examples:

```
   char lowercase( char *stringToLower)
    {   
        int i; //local counter i

        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         stringToLower[i] = toupper(stringToLower[i]);
        return i;

    }// end make LOWERcase
```

and this one as well

```
void countWordsLower( char *stringToLower)
{
    // define local variables 
    char *tokenPtr;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    printf( "\nThe string to be tokenized is:\n");
    puts( stringToLower );

    tokenPtr = strtok( stringToLower, " \n"); 

    // tokenize until tokenPtr becomes NULL
    while ( tokenPtr ) 
    {
        ++counter;
        //increment counter
        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, " \n" ); 
        // gets next token

    } // end while 

    printf( "\nThe total number of words is %d\n\n", counter );

} // end countWords LOWER
```

these are their prototypes

```
void countWordsLower ( char *stringToLower );
char lowercase ( char *stringToLower );
```

The entire program in context is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Function prototypes 
void concatenate ( char *stringFirst, char *stringSecond );
char lowercase ( char *stringToLower ); 
char uppercase ( char *stringToUpper );
void countWordsLower ( char *stringToLower );
void countWordsUpper ( char *stringToUpper );
void twoStrings ( char *stringFirst, char *stringSecond );

int main (void)
{
    // initialize variables 
    int menuOption; // user choice
    int tokens; // holds return value from tokenize 
    char stringToLower [100]; // 99 character string
    char stringToUpper [100]; // 99 character string
    char stringFirst [100]; //first string able to hold 99 chars
    char stringSecond [100];//second string able to hold 99 chars

    do 
    {
        printf ( "\n\nWelcome!\n" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 1 for Concatenate Two Strings\n" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 2 for Change to LOWER Case with Word Count" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 3 for Change to UPPER Case with Word Count" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 4 to Terminate program" );

        printf ( "\n\nPlease enter your selection: " );
        scanf( "%d", &menuOption );
        // list menu options
        switch (menuOption)
        {
            case 1:
                //Concatenate Two Strings
                printf( "\nThis function will concatenate two strings into a third\n");
                printf( "Enter first string:\n\n\t");
                gets( stringFirst );

                printf( "Enter second string:\n\n\t" );
                gets( stringSecond );

            //function to concatenate
            twoStrings( stringFirst, stringSecond );
                break;
                //end choice one

            case 2:
                //Change to LOWER Case with Word Count
                printf( "\nThis function will change an entire string to LOWER case\n");
                printf( "\nand count the number of words!\n");
                printf( "Enter string:\n\n\t");
                gets( stringToLower );

                //function to change to lowercase
                lowercase( char &stringToLower );

                //function to count number of words
                countWordsLower( char &stringToLower );

                break;

            case 3:
                //Change to UPPER Case with Word Count
                printf( "\nThis function will change an entire string to UPPER case\n");
                printf( "\nand count the number of words!\n");
                printf( "Enter string:\n\n\t");
                gets( stringToUpper );

                //function to change to uppercase
                uppercase( char &stringToUpper);

                //function to count number of words
                countWordsUpper( char &stringToUpper);
                break;

            case 4:
                //End Program
                printf( "\nThank You!\n Come Again!\n\n" );
                break;

            default:
                printf ( "\nWhoops!  Try a number 1,2,3 or 4!\n" );

        }//end switch

    }// end do

    while (menuOption != 4);


}// end main
void concatenate ( char *stringFirst, char *stringSecond)
{
    char stringThird[200]; 


    printf( "\nString ois %s\nString two is %s\n", stringFirst, stringSecond );


    // concatenate stringFirst to stringSecond with space 
    strcpy(stringThird, stringFirst);
    strcat(stringThird, " ");
    strcat(stringThird, stringSecond);


    printf( "\nTogether ... %s\n\n", stringThird );


} // end concatenate

//function to make LOWERcase
char lowercase( char *stringToLower)
{   
    int i; //local counter i

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     stringToLower[i] = toupper(stringToLower[i]);
    return i;

}// end make LOWERcase


    // function to count number of words
    // in string that was made LOWERcase
void countWordsLower( char *stringToLower)
{
    // define local variables 
    char *tokenPtr;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    printf( "\nThe string to be tokenized is:\n");
    puts( stringToLower );

    tokenPtr = strtok( stringToLower, " \n"); 

    // tokenize until tokenPtr becomes NULL
    while ( tokenPtr ) 
    {
        ++counter;
        //increment counter
        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, " \n" ); 
        // gets next token

    } // end while 

    printf( "\nThe total number of words is %d\n\n", counter );

} // end countWords LOWER

//function to make UPPERcase
char uppercase( char *stringToUpper )
{
    int i; //local counter i

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        stringToUpper[i] = toupper(stringToUpper[i]);
    return i;
}// end make UPPERcase

    // function to count number of words
    // in string that was made UPPERcase
void countWordsUpper( char *stringToUpper )
{
    // define local variables 
    char *tokenPtr;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;


    printf( "\nThe string to be tokenized is:\n");
    puts( stringToUpper );


    tokenPtr = strtok( stringToUpper, " \n"); 


    // tokenize until tokenPtr becomes NULL 
    while ( tokenPtr ) 
    {
        ++counter;
        //increment counter
        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
        // gets next token 


    } // end while 

    printf( "\nThe total number of words is %d\n\n", counter );


} // end countWords UPPER
```

Here are the errors that result from compiling the above code in one C compiler:

```
main.c:58:38: error: expected ')'
                char lowercase( char &stringToLower );
                                     ^
main.c:58:31: note: to match this '('
                char lowercase( char &stringToLower );
                              ^
main.c:58:22: error: conflicting types for 'lowercase'
                char lowercase( char &stringToLower );
                     ^
main.c:7:6: note: previous declaration is here
char lowercase ( char *stringToLower ); 
     ^
main.c:61:44: error: expected ')'
                void countWordsLower( char &stringToLower );
                                           ^
main.c:61:37: note: to match this '('
                void countWordsLower( char &stringToLower );
                                    ^
main.c:61:22: error: conflicting types for 'countWordsLower'
                void countWordsLower( char &stringToLower );
                     ^
main.c:9:6: note: previous declaration is here
void countWordsLower ( char *stringToLower );
     ^
main.c:73:38: error: expected ')'
                char uppercase( char &stringToUpper);
                                     ^
main.c:73:31: note: to match this '('
                char uppercase( char &stringToUpper);
                              ^
main.c:73:22: error: conflicting types for 'uppercase'
                char uppercase( char &stringToUpper);
                     ^
main.c:8:6: note: previous declaration is here
char uppercase ( char *stringToUpper );
     ^
main.c:76:44: error: expected ')'
                void countWordsUpper( char &stringToUpper);
                                           ^
main.c:76:37: note: to match this '('
                void countWordsUpper( char &stringToUpper);
                                    ^
main.c:76:22: error: conflicting types for 'countWordsUpper'
                void countWordsUpper( char &stringToUpper);
                     ^
main.c:10:6: note: previous declaration is here
void countWordsUpper ( char *stringToUpper );
     ^
```

changed...again

```
                //function to change to lowercase
                lowercase( stringToLower );

                //function to count number of words
                countWordsLower( stringToLower );
```

for anyone still paying attention the final code as I finally fixed it is this

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Function prototypes 
void concatenate ( char *stringFirst, char *stringSecond );
char lowercase ( char *stringToLower ); 
char uppercase ( char *stringToUpper );
void countWordsLower ( char *stringToLower );
void countWordsUpper ( char *stringToUpper );

int main (void)
{
    // initialize variables 
    int menuOption; // user choice
    int tokens = 0; // holds return value from tokenize 
    char stringToLower [100]; // 99 character string
    char stringToUpper [100]; // 99 character string
    char stringFirst [100]; //first string able to hold 99 chars
    char stringSecond [100];//second string able to hold 99 chars

    do 
    {
        printf ( "\n\nWelcome!\n" );
        printf ( "\n""*Concatenate*""" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 1 for Concatenate Two Strings\n" );
        printf ( "\n""*Change Case*""" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 2 for Change to LOWER Case with Word Count" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 3 for Change to UPPER Case with Word Count\n" );
        printf ( "\n""*Exit*""" );
        printf ( "\nEnter 4 to Terminate program" );

        printf ( "\n\nPlease enter your selection: " );
        scanf( "%d", &menuOption );
        _flushall();

        // list menu options
        switch (menuOption)
        {
            case 1:
                //Concatenate Two Strings
                printf( "\nThis function will concatenate two strings into a third\n");
                printf( "\nEnter first string:  ");
                fgets( stringFirst, 99, stdin );
                strtok( stringFirst, "\n" );
                printf( "\nEnter second string:  " );
                strtok( stringSecond, "\n" );
                fgets( stringSecond, 99, stdin );

            //function to concatenate
            concatenate ( stringFirst, stringSecond );
                break;
                //end choice one

            case 2:
                //Change to LOWER Case with Word Count
                printf( "\nThis function will change an entire string to LOWER case\n");
                printf( "and count the number of words!\n");
                printf( "\nEnter string:  ");
                fgets( stringToLower, 99, stdin );
                printf( "\nThe original string is:  " );
                printf( "%s", stringToLower );


                //function to change to lowercase
                lowercase( stringToLower);

                //function to count number of words
                countWordsLower( stringToLower);

                break;

            case 3:
                //Change to UPPER Case with Word Count
                printf( "\nThis function will change an entire string to UPPER case\n");
                printf( "and count the number of words!\n");
                printf( "\nEnter string:  ");
                fgets( stringToUpper, 99, stdin );
                printf( "\nThe original string is:  " );
                printf( "%s", stringToUpper );

                //function to change to uppercase
                uppercase( stringToUpper );

                //function to count number of words
                countWordsUpper( stringToUpper );
                break;

            case 4:
                //End Program
                printf( "\nThank You!\n Come Again!\n\n" );
                break;

            default:
                printf ( "\nWhoops!  Try a number 1,2,3 or 4!\n" );

        }//end switch

    }// end do

    while (menuOption != 4);


}// end main
void concatenate ( char *stringFirst, char *stringSecond )
{
    char stringThird[200]; 


    printf( "\n\nString One is: %s\nString Two is: %s\n", stringFirst, stringSecond );


    // concatenate stringFirst to stringSecond with space 
    strcpy(stringThird, stringFirst);
    strcat(stringThird, " / ");
    strcat(stringThird, stringSecond);


    printf( "Together they read:  %s", stringThird );


} // end concatenate

//function to make LOWERcase
char lowercase( char *stringToLower )
{   
    int i; //local counter i

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     stringToLower[i] = tolower(stringToLower[i]);
    return i;

}// end make LOWERcase


    // function to count number of words
    // in string that was made LOWERcase
void countWordsLower( char *stringToLower )
{
    // define local variables 
    char *tokenPtr;
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    printf( "\nThe adjusted string is:  ");
    puts( stringToLower );

    tokenPtr = strtok( stringToLower, " \n"); 

    // tokenize until tokenPtr becomes NULL
    while ( tokenPtr ) 
    {
        ++counter;
        //increment counter
        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, " \n" ); 
        // gets next token

    } // end while 

    printf( "The total number of words is %d\n", counter );

} // end countWords LOWER

//function to make UPPERcase
char uppercase( char *stringToUpper )
{
    int i = 0; //local counter i

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        stringToUpper[i] = toupper(stringToUpper[i]);
    return i;
}// end make UPPERcase

    // function to count number of words
    // in string that was made UPPERcase
void countWordsUpper( char *stringToUpper )
{
    // define local variables 
    char *tokenPtr;
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;


    printf( "\nThe adjusted string is:  ");
    puts( stringToUpper );


    tokenPtr = strtok( stringToUpper, " \n"); 


    // tokenize until tokenPtr becomes NULL 
    while ( tokenPtr ) 
    {
        ++counter;
        //increment counter
        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
        // gets next token 


    } // end while 

    printf( "The total number of words is %d\n", counter );


} // end countWords UPPER
```

by the way, thank you for all the answers and support!

Comment: And, the errors you receive are .......

Comment: What are the errors and which lines are causing them?

Comment: Don't use `gets`; it's inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language. It can't guard against an overly long input line. `fgets` is a little more complicated to use, but it can be used safely.

Comment: Linker errors because he (correctly) decided to change the name of twoStrings( to concatenate() but (incorrectly) didn't follow through. The rest is compiling but not working, partly  for the reasons given by the answers below and partly because of the unavoidable gets()/newline issues.

Comment: Funny, I didn't get any of these errors with VS Express 2013.

Comment: @mafso You are correct about gets() and scanf(). It's just bad to mix them, exactly because as you say scanf() leaves the newline dangling (which the OP didn't do). As to security... I wouldn't say "insecure"== "wrong", but it's close, admittedly. And in the newest standards gets() is or will be wrong proper.

Comment: Yeah it appears that some of the warnings arise from using VS2008 ( I am running Windows 7, I couldnt get 2013 to run.

Comment: But fgets appears to be the solution for the gets warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code snippet, you have it wrong:

```
//function to change to uppercase
char uppercase( char &stringToUpper);

//function to count number of words
void countWordsUpper( char &stringToUpper);
break;
```

When you ***call*** a function, you do ***not*** include the return type, nor the types of the parameters.  (those are only used when declaring and defining functions, not when using them)

The code should be:

```
//function to change to uppercase
uppercase(stringToUpper);

//function to count number of words
countWordsUpper(stringToUpper);
break;
```

Comment: Same as above this corrects that particular error but now I have a slew of other errors.

Comment: You ***must*** show your corrected code, and be precise about your "slew of other errors". (what line number are they on? What is the full and exact error message?)

Comment: Sorry, I am new here.  errors are as follows, each repeated for lines 62, 65, 77, and 80. error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type' error C2198: 'countWordsUpper' : too few arguments for call error C2059: syntax error : ')'.  Code edited above

Comment: It seems you have not ***read*** and ***understood*** the answer that both Paul Roub and I gave you.   It looks like you are still making the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're (not-quite-)declaring functions in the middle of main, instead of calling them. For instance, when you say:

```
char lowercase( char &stringToLower );

//function to count number of words
void countWordsLower( char &stringToLower );
```

Those are (invalid) function prototypes. You want to say:

```
lowercase( stringToLower );
countWordsLower( stringToLower );
```

Comment: Because `char uppercase( char &stringToUpper);` isn't valid C no matter *where* it's placed in the file.

Comment: Oh, that's why I didn't get errors -- I compiled as C++.

Comment: OK this appears to correct that error!  Thanks!  But now I am getting this series of errors for each call:                 error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'           
error C2198: 'countWordsUpper' : too few arguments for call          
error C2059: syntax error : ')'